# How can I structure data in firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I have data about family, family members, and children.

1. User can add children.
2. User can create a family.
3. User can add as many other users to the family.
4. All family members can access the children's data of all other family members.

what I decided is something like,

```
User:
    user_1:
       name: name,
       email: email,
       familyId: family_1
    user_2:
       name : name,
       email: email,
       familyId: family_1

Family:
    family_1:
      familyName: name
      creator: user_1

Children:
    child_1:
      name: name,
      parentId: user_1
    child_2:
      name: name,
      parentId: user_1
```

using this user can access his own children and the family can access all family members. But how can family members access family children's data?

anyone who can guide.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Can you edit your question to show what you tried already?

Comment: I have updated the question you can check actually I'm developing and I can't figure out how all children of the same family can be acessed

Comment: Your question asks how to Sort Data, but the content in the question is unrelated to sorting data and more about structuring data. Additionally, as shown, family members *can* access family childrens data. A family has a user, like user_1 and the childen also tie back to user_1, therefore a family can access any children. So what's the issue? Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with rules, but this does require you to know the child's UID since you can't query children if you can't read all nodes in the structure.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "children": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && data.child('parentId').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To read the child node based on the Family ID, you will need to maintain a list of users who are in the family

```
Family:
    family_1:
      familyName: name
      creator: user_1
      members: user_1 : true
               user_2 : true
```

and the corresponding rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Children": {
      "$child_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && 
               root.child('Family').child(
                 root.child('User').child(
                   data.child('parentId').val()
                 ).val()
               ).child('members').child(auth.uid).exists()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can also swap out the last `.exists()` for a `.val()` allowing you to test against `true` so you can essentially blacklist members if you desire.

Comment: If you need a deeper dive or further details in the answer, please let me know.

Comment: "To read the child node based on the Family ID, you will need to maintain a list of users who are in the family". you mean to say every family will access other family members Uid from family and on that member UId every child can be accessed?

Comment: Only users who are in the 'members' list have access to that specified family and its children. if you have multiple users who should be able to read the child of that family, they would be on the member list in that specific family.

Since your current data structure doesn't support any assignable means from child to family with any other Auth UID - you could restrict it to only the family creator only but without context, this may be undesirable for you.

Comment: I want to say when a child only has parentID (that can be passed as a credential to access that child)  then how can other family members access all children of the family

Comment: the first rule with `data.child('parentId').val() === auth.uid"` meets your first condition, the second version of the rules is how you would obtain that second result.

it does this by looking at the 'parent' and then getting the parents family, and checking if the current user, is in the member list.

Comment: if this does answer your question, please accept this answer.

Comment: actually, in the child node, there is an entity 'parentId'. By using 'parentId' i can access all the children having authenticated user-id. But there is no node in child to directly access family children by other family members. Or I have to access the list of all family members and then on  those members-id base I can access all children

Comment: exactly, there is no relational data in your current setup for that scenario. you will need to add it.

Comment: just last thing I want to know. Does rules as you wrote in answer. Can be used to get values desired values? or these are just validations of who can access that data or not.

Comment: yes, this is for another question, but to summarise: you can use `val()` to return the VALUE of the path, and `exists()` to see if a value exists or not. `val` is simply a short hand for `value`

Comment: ok thank you so much for your time I'll study more about returning values on the basis of defined rules. Do suggest to me any website or content from where I can learn about it.

Comment: Honestly, the best location online is the Firebase Developers Discord server - https://discord.firebase.me/ I run it with several other firebase developers